# JAX-RS (Jersey) and Jackson does not serialize LocalDate correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

We recently upgraded to Spring Boot `2.0`, and with that, JAX-RS at `2.1` and Jackson at `2.26`.

The issue now is that the Java object I'm trying to (serialize and) send via `POST` has a field of type `java.time.LocalDate` and it's not getting serialized (into JSON) correctly. This is the result after the updates:

```
...
"birthDate": {
  "year": 1991,
  "month": "JANUARY",
  "chronology": {
    "id": "ISO",
    "calendarType": "iso8601"
  },
  "monthValue": 1,
  "dayOfMonth": 1,
  "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
  "era": "CE",
  "dayOfYear": 1,
  "leapYear": false
},
...
```

...instead, `birthDate` should be sent like `"birthDate": "1991-01-01"` — as it was before.

The client is configured as:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
final JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider();
provider.setMapper(mapper);
return ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig(provider))
    .target("http://hostname/api/some-path")
    .path("");
```

I also tried annotating the `birthDate` filed with `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")`.

Comment: There a module for Jackson to enable JSR310 in the serialization. It's documented on the official website.

Comment: Yes, for Java 8 (and onward) date/time types the `JavaTimeModule` (that I'm used) is the way to go. It just stops working after that upgrade...not sure what's happening there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, after the upgrade, what works was:

- Delete `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` dependency
- Add `org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson` dependency
- Fix any compilation problems that you have `:troll_face:`
- Use `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` instead of `JacksonJsonProvider` — this one was completely unexpected for me

In the end, the final configuration for the client looks like this one:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
    .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
return ClientBuilder.newClient() // ClientConfig if needed
    .register(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider(mapper, JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.DEFAULT_ANNOTATIONS))
    .target("http://hostname/api/some-path")
    .path("");
```